# PHP - replacing dynamically created content

Tags: php

I have a lot of these in a file `jQuery1332199407617="01"` that need removing, however, the bunch of numbers of always different, is that any way I can just deleted everything between `jQuery` and `="(number is also always different)"`?

Thanks in advance.

Sample of part of the file as requested: 
(as you can see it adds another jQuery thing each time it is saved.. hence the need to remove it)

`<H2 editing="false" revert="Projects:" jQuery1332198888840="12" jQuery1332199361841="12" jQuery1332199407617="12">ProjectsTesting</H2>
<UL class=list1 jQuery1332198888840="17" jQuery1332199361841="17" jQuery1332199407617="17">
<LI jQuery1332198888840="16" jQuery1332199361841="16" jQuery1332199407617="16"><A href="#" jQuery1332198888840="15" jQuery1332199361841="15" jQuery1332199407617="15">Praesent vestibulum molestie </A>
<LI jQuery1332198888840="19" jQuery1332199361841="19" jQuery1332199407617="19"><A href="#" jQuery1332198888840="18" jQuery1332199361841="18" jQuery1332199407617="18">Aenean nonummy </A>
<LI jQuery1332198888840="21" jQuery1332199361841="21" jQuery1332199407617="21"><A href="#" jQuery1332198888840="20" jQuery1332199361841="20" jQuery1332199407617="20">Hendrerit mauris phasellus </A>
<LI jQuery1332198888840="23" jQuery1332199361841="23" jQuery1332199407617="23"><A href="#" jQuery1332198888840="22" jQuery1332199361841="22" jQuery1332199407617="22">Porta fusce suscipit varius </A>
<LI jQuery1332198888840="25" jQuery1332199361841="25" jQuery1332199407617="25"><A href="#" jQuery1332198888840="24" jQuery1332199361841="24" jQuery1332199407617="24">Cum sociis natoque</A> 
<LI jQuery1332198888840="27" jQuery1332199361841="27" jQuery1332199407617="27"><A href="#" jQuery1332198888840="26" jQuery1332199361841="26" jQuery1332199407617="26">Penatibus et magnis dis</A>I 
<LI jQuery1332198888840="29" jQuery1332199361841="29" jQuery1332199407617="29"><A href="#" jQuery1332198888840="28" jQuery1332199361841="28" jQuery1332199407617="28">Parturient montes</A> </LI></UL></DIV>`

Comment: I was thinking preg_match but idk how to repalce things with it :/ and i fail at regex

Comment: Are you sure that stuff is actually in the source document? And not only in the browser's rendered DOM?

Comment: its in the source document definately.. ( the file comes from a div that is simply saved )

Comment: Really? To me it looks like some jQuery-IE-compatibility plugin's output.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the file?

Comment: search/replace in a text editor?

Comment: @techouse yes it is but it's also written to file

Comment: Hmm, ok. Looks like your caching it somehow broken otherwise I fail to see why this is happening to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will remove the jQuery text, no matter what numbers are present. It will also take out the excessive space at the end of the tags which is left after the jQuery tags were removed.

```
$old = '<H2 editing="false" revert="Projects:" jQuery1332198888840="12" jQuery1332199361841="12" jQuery1332199407617="12">ProjectsTesting</H2> <UL class=list1 jQuery1332198888840="17" jQuery1332199361841="17" jQuery1332199407617="17"> <LI jQuery1332198888840="16" jQuery1332199361841="16" jQuery1332199407617="16"><A href="#" jQuery1332198888840="15" jQuery1332199361841="15" jQuery1332199407617="15">Praesent vestibulum molestie </A> <LI jQuery1332198888840="19" jQuery1332199361841="19" jQuery1332199407617="19"><A href="#" jQuery1332198888840="18" jQuery1332199361841="18" jQuery1332199407617="18">Aenean nonummy </A> <LI jQuery1332198888840="21" jQuery1332199361841="21" jQuery1332199407617="21"><A href="#" jQuery1332198888840="20" jQuery1332199361841="20" jQuery1332199407617="20">Hendrerit mauris phasellus </A> <LI jQuery1332198888840="23" jQuery1332199361841="23" jQuery1332199407617="23"><A href="#" jQuery1332198888840="22" jQuery1332199361841="22" jQuery1332199407617="22">Porta fusce suscipit varius </A> <LI jQuery1332198888840="25" jQuery1332199361841="25" jQuery1332199407617="25"><A href="#" jQuery1332198888840="24" jQuery1332199361841="24" jQuery1332199407617="24">Cum sociis natoque</A> <LI jQuery1332198888840="27" jQuery1332199361841="27" jQuery1332199407617="27"><A href="#" jQuery1332198888840="26" jQuery1332199361841="26" jQuery1332199407617="26">Penatibus et magnis dis</A>I <LI jQuery1332198888840="29" jQuery1332199361841="29" jQuery1332199407617="29"><A href="#" jQuery1332198888840="28" jQuery1332199361841="28" jQuery1332199407617="28">Parturient montes</A> </LI></UL></DIV>';

//This will erase all the jQuery strings.
$new = preg_replace('/jQuery\d+="\d+"/', '', $old);

//This will take out the extra spaces at the end of the tags that was left open.
$new = preg_replace('/\s+>/', '>', $new);

echo $new;
```

For more information see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: You may have made a mistake in testing it. I have tested the code and verified it as working using your example input. All the jQuery tags and extra spaces are removed from $new.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, this should work:

```
$myContent = preg_replace('/jQuery\d+="(\d+)"/g', 'jQuery="${1}"', $myContent);
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Uh I get this error: 
Error: Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: Add a forward slash to the start and end of the regular expression. Make sure you're using `preg_replace`, not `preg_match`.